# NullPointerException when calling rawquery()

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am executing following code:

```
String sql = "Select * from NetOrderID where (flag='0')";
Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null) ;
```

Logcat:

```
08-16 19:09:54.868: W/System.err(10911): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I dont understand why am I getting this error even when this query is executing successfully on actual database.

Comment: Then check if your mDb object is null

Comment: mDb is null...[Why null pointer exception ?](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/why-nullpointerexception-occures-in.html)

Comment: learn to debug : http://www.cavdar.net/2008/09/13/5-tips-for-debugging-java-code-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 2):

`mDb` in the below section could possibly be `null`.

```
Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Make sure you are instantiating or getting an object for `mDb` before trying to use it.

Try something like the following:

```
if (mDb != null) {
    Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
} else {
    /* handle the null scenario, instantiate an object or try and get one */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you initialised mDb like this...?

```
mDb =  openOrCreateDatabase("DataBase.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
```